# Why do we need request.getSession(true)?

Tags: servlets, httpsession

When I first started learning J2EE, I was told that, we need to call `request.getSession(true)` to create a new session. But when I started testing `HttpSessionListener`, I found that the servlet container will create a HttpSession as soon as it receives a Http request from the client - before I explicitly try to create any session. Is the servlet container implicitly calling `request.getSession()` or `request.getSessioin(true)` to create a new session from me?

The only scenario where I found the `getSession(true)` to be useful is when I want to explicitly invalidate the existing session and create a new one. Is this the only real world scenario or are there any other examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I started testing HttpSessionListener, I found that the servlet container will create a HttpSession as soon as it receives a Http request from the client - before I explicitly try to create any session

I don't know how you tested it, but unfortunately it is not true. Try to create very simple servlet and put there:

```
System.out.println("Session: " + request.getSession(false));
```

you will see that session is `null`. Container doesn't create sessions, if it is not requested by your application.

You probably got that impression testing jsp pages, or some framework, which by default create session. But this can also be disabled using `<%@ page session="false" %>`, if your page doesn't need session.

And regarding need of `request.getSession(true)` - you could say it is not needed as `request.getSession()` does exactly the same, however `request.getSession(false)` is needed to check, if there is a valid session associated with request.

Comment: I saw the behavior when using struts 1.3 framework. I need to check if struts is creating a session for me.

Comment: In the scenarios without struts, if the session is not created until we explicitly call request.getSession(), how does the server maintain conversation with the browser - since there is no session id at all? Or is it the other way around? Since there is no session id, there is no conversation..

Comment: ok.. I checked again.. session is actually created from the jsp... thanks again!